# Is Azure Notification Hub using the FCM Legacy API

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm currenyly using Google (GCM/FCM).

And register the token to the hub using GCMTemplateRegistrationDescription
With the tempate below

```
{
    "data": {
        "message": "$(message)",
        "id": "$(id)",
        "title": "$(title)",
    }
}
```

[image]

is this using the FCM Legacy API?

If i have to migration to FCMV1, is this the correct payload template i have to transform to ?

```
{
    "message":{
        "data": {
            "message": "$(message)",
            "id": "$(id)",
            "title": "$(title)",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the fragment of screenshot in your question refers to the old FCM Legacy configuration.

And as to the message formats: also yes. Based on the FCM migration [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#example-simple-notification-message) the message templates you posted are appropriate for the old and the new format respectively.

Note that you use 'data' (as opposed to 'notification') field which is used for custom data structures which means appropriate changes need to be applied on the mobile client side too.